# Can I use string interpolation using a ternary operator that displays different strings in twig?

Tags: twig, octobercms, craftcms

Can I use string interpolation using a ternary operator that displays different strings in twig?

I've been trying variations of the following

```
<div {{ items|length > 1 ? 'data-item data-target="#{props.target}"' : '' }}
```

```
<div {{ items|length > 1 ? 'data-item data-target="'~props.target~'"' : '' }}
```

The desired outcome is if the length of items is more than one is

```
<div data-item data-target="some-value">
```

Is this possible - for the purpose of keeping things looking tidier? Or is this a bit much?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you'd only have to keep in mind `twig` will not mark the output as safe when concating a string and a variable, so u'd need the `raw` filter as well. In `twig` you can omit the right hand side of the tenary operator.

```
<div {{ items|length ? ('data-item data-target="'~props.target~'"')|raw }}></div>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/25sol2)